# Add timezone offset to java date

Tags: java

I have a requirement to add my local timezone offset to a date that I am reading from the database (i.e. the business date field below) which will then be tranformed into an epoch date (businessDate.getTime()).

```
public List<Long> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Date businessDate = rs.getDate(BUSINESS_DATE);
    Integer numberOfTxns = rs.getInt(TRAN_COUNT);

    List<Long> count = new ArrayList<Long>();
    count.add(businessDate.getTime());
    count.add(new Long(numberOfTxns));

    return count;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get time zone offset this way

```
    int offsetInMilliseconds = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(date.getTime());
```

Comment: So I should just be able to add that offset to my businessDate.getTime() and that will return the unix time stamp with a time zone offset?

Comment: To be exact, you will get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT + local time zone offset in milliseconds